# How to order rows by a field that exists on both table while using JOIN statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli

Main Table: 'posts'.
Structure:

```
id || text || time || user_id
```

Secondary table: 'likes'.
Structure:

```
id || post_id || time || user_id
```

Here, the post_id from the 2nd table can (& must) be an ID from the 1st table. I am running a query where I fetch all IDs from the posts table of a specific user_id and also all POST_IDs from the likes table of a specific user_id. This is the query:

```
SELECT p.id FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN likes l ON p.id=l.post_id 
WHERE p.user_id=$userid OR   
l.user_id=$userid
```

The time field on both table is numeric, type int (12). The Unix timestamp is stored in here, like *1234567890*. I would like to order the data I'm fetching by the time field on both table.

For example, there are 2 posts in posts table, post with ID 1 has a time value of 1234567891, post with ID 2 has a time value of 1234567896. And there's 1 post with ID 3 in likes table with a time value of 1234567893.

I would like to order the rows by time, like this:

Post ID 1, Post ID 3, Post ID 2.

As Post ID 3 occured before Post ID 2. How do I go about it since the time and it's value can be in either tables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After the join you have two time columns, one from each table. You need to give SQL some logic to use to order by both - for example, ordering by MAX(l.time,p.time) for whichever is greater.

Basically, when you say "I would like to order the data I'm fetching by the time field on both table", you need to define that more clearly, and then it should be straightforward to do what you want. Try thinking about how you would do it by hand, or how you would instruct someone to do it by hand - if you just handed them these records on pieces of paper and said "put these in order by the time fields in both sets of data", they wouldn't know what to do - and neither does MySQL!

Answer (score 0):

Try using CASE expression in ORDER BY clause. ORDER BY CASE WHEN p.time < l.time THEN p.time ELSE l.time END CASE

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to use a union statement to put those time values into the one column. Try something like this:

```
SELECT id from 
(SELECT p.id, p.time FROM posts p
WHERE p.user_id=$userid
union all 
SELECT l.id, l.time FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN likes l ON p.id=l.post_id 
WHERE p.user_id=$userid OR   
l.user_id=$userid) allposts
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: I get this error: Unknown column 'l.user_id' in 'where clause' :/

Comment: Not sure if you grabbed the latest version, I edited it after posting... should work now I think.

Comment: Hi, No rows from the likes table are fetched.

Comment: That suggests either there are no rows in the likes table with a post_id that matches the ID in your posts tables, or that there are no rows with the requested user_id in the likes table.

Comment: There are rows. I checked the database & also, my original query in the question's description fetches the rows from the likes table but not in the order of time.